# Create custom component input for react-day-picker

Tags: javascript, reactjs, material-ui, react-day-picker

I was creating a custom materiel UI component for DayPickerInput, but the problem is when **onDayChange** is fired,it gives an error.

```
handleToDateChange = (selectedDay, modifiers, dayPickerInput) => {
    const val = dayPickerInput.getInput().value;
}

Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'value' of null
```

**DayPickerInput Component**

```
 <DayPickerInput
      component={props => <DatePickerCustomInput {...props} />}
      value={toDate}
      placeholder=""
      formatDate={this.setDatePickerformatDate}
      onDayChange={this.handleToDateChange}
  />
```

**DayPickerInput Custom Component**

```
class DatePickerCustomInput extends Component {
   render() {
       return (
           <TextField {...this.props}
               InputProps={{
                   startAdornment: (
                       <InputAdornment position="start">
                           <DateRange />
                       </InputAdornment>
                   ),
               }}

               value={this.props.value}
           />
       );
   }
}
```

to reproduce the issue : https://codesandbox.io/s/387r9plx65

Answer (score 0):

Try do this!

```
handleToDateChange = (selectedDay, modifiers, dayPickerInput) => {
    const val = dayPickerInput.state.value;
}
```

Comment: so is this the best practice to get a child state by calling component.state in react ?

Answer (score 0):

[From the docs here](https://react-day-picker.js.org/api/DayPickerInput). The `onDayChange` method has a signature of

`onDayChange (day: date, modifiers: Object, e: SyntheticEvent) ⇒ void`

`day` is a date object referring to the selected date in the picker. You don't need to pull the value out of the event to get the selected date.